# SQL function to get the sum of datetime column values for each ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-function

I have a column ID which has values 10,20,10,10,60,60 and so on. I have another column which is a diff of (modified_date - created_date) as TS which has datetime values like `6 5:28:13.0` (6 is the days), `1 1:34:54.0` and so on for each ID. How can I get the total days and time for each ID value? For example: how can I get the total value of TS for ID = 10?

[image: sample data picture]

From the image: for each value of `eowstage_nbr` column, how can I get total days and time in column `TS`?

Comment: Please provide sample data data and desired results as *text tables*.  Also, tag with the database you are using.

Comment: would love to see your efforts in the form of queries you tried

Comment: @Codeek - in the first place can two values in datetime format add up ? i have tried avg function but returns me a datatype error.

Comment: @sree if the answers below help you then t would be a good thing to mark them as answer and close the question. If they don't let us know what is it that they are lacking for your problem

Answer (score 0):

A regular `sum()` aggregation over the ID column combined with some data type conversions should do it...

**Sample data**

```
create table data
(
  id int,
  created datetime,
  updated datetime
);

insert into data (id, created, updated) values
(10, '2020-01-01 00:00:00', '2020-01-01 05:00:10'),
(10, '2020-01-02 00:00:00', '2020-01-03 11:00:03'),
(20, '2020-02-05 00:00:00', '2020-02-05 01:02:03'),
(20, '2020-02-15 00:10:00', '2020-02-17 00:00:10');
```

**Solution**

Describing the steps in plain English would sound like:

1. Take the difference between the `created` and `updated` timestamp, expressed in seconds;
2. add them up the seconds for each `id`;
3. convert the seconds to a suitable date format.

I took care of step 3 by adding the seconds up to a reference date `1900-01-01`.

Query version:

```
select d.id,
       dateadd(second, sum(datediff(second, d.created, d.updated)), '1900-01-01 00:00:00') as diff_sum
from data d
group by d.id;
```

**Result**

The values are not formatted like in your screenshot, but that should boil down to data type selection, datetime formatting and localization.

```
id diff_sum
-- -----------------------
10 1900-01-02 16:00:13.000
20 1900-01-03 00:52:13.000
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=87e30b3b64157b54f409c58c0e3b5c9a)

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not give any sample data and looking at your immage I assume you have data in TS column as per your image. (I have used dummy data to replicate your TS column). So the steps would be to separate day from time in your TS column, then converting that time into seconds, and doing summation of those seconds and days seperately, and finally combining the days and seconds converted to proper d hh:mm:ss format.

```
select ID, 
cast((sum(noofdays) + SUM(DATEDIFF(S, '00:00:00', noofhrs))/3600/24) as varchar(5)) + ' ' + 
right('00'+CAST(SUM(DATEDIFF(S, '00:00:00', noofhrs))/3600%24 AS VARCHAR(2)),2) + ':'
+ right('00'+CAST(SUM(DATEDIFF(S, '00:00:00', noofhrs))%3600/60 AS VARCHAR(2)),2) + ':'
+ right('00'+CAST(((SUM(DATEDIFF(S, '00:00:00', noofhrs))%3600)%60) AS VARCHAR(2)),2)
from 
(
 select ID, case left(TS,charindex(' ',TS)) when '' then 0 else left(TS,charindex(' ',TS)) end as noofdays,
cast(right(TS,len(TS)-charindex(' ',TS)) as datetime) as noofhrs from 
(
select 1 ID,'6 5:28:13.0' TS union
select 1,'1 8:28:13.0' a union
select 1,'2 12:28:13.0' a union
select 2,'5:28:13.0' a union
select 2,'6 5:28:13.0' a
)
tablename
) A
group by ID
```